# How can I display links in 2 rows?

Tags: html, css

Basicly links can be generated it could be anything from one link to 20 links depending on the user.

This is how I want it to look

[image: a]

But how can I make sure that it adds links in this way?

This is the css(the html code is in the jsfiddle)

```
.document-list {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.number {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0084c9;
    border-radius: 50000px;
    color: #0084c9;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
}
.document-item {
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
```

This is how it looks right now:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6P5xg/)

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Could you provide the html aswell?

Comment: you can find it in the jsfiddle

Comment: use table to achieve this

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/6P5xg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add the following styles:

```
.document-item {
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:50%; 
    float:left;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/6P5xg/5/)

Also note this few improvements:

```
.number {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0084c9;
    border-radius: 50%;  
    color: #0084c9;
    text-align: center;
    width:  1.3em; /* don't use padding for that ... */
    height: 1.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to set the width, for example 50% and float left.

```
.document-item {
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6P5xg/3/).

It's as simple as this.

I just add two extra classes `odd` and `even` to all the `.document-list`.

```
<div class="document-list">
<div class="document-item odd">
    <div class="number">1</div> <a href="#">Testing link 1</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item even">
    <div class="number">2</div> <a href="#">Testing link 2</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item odd">
    <div class="number">3</div> <a href="#">Testing link 3</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item even">
    <div class="number">4</div> <a href="#">Testing link 4</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item odd">
    <div class="number">5</div> <a href="#">Testing link 5</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item even">
    <div class="number">6</div> <a href="#">Testing link 6</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item odd">
    <div class="number">7</div> <a href="#">Testing link 7</a> 
</div>
<div class="document-item even">
    <div class="number">8</div> <a href="#">Testing link 8</a> 
</div>
```

And a block of CSS code.

```
.odd {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `document-item` as,

```
.document-item {
   margin-bottom:8px;
   display:inline-block;
   width:calc(50% - 40px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    float:right
}
```

Here's my take:

http://jsfiddle.net/6P5xg/4/

Comment: Check this jsfiddle I tried your and depending on text length it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6P5xg/4/

Answer (score 0):

html format

```
<div class="document-list">
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">1</div> <a href="#">Testing link 1 </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">2</div> <a href="#">Testing link 2</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">3</div> <a href="#">Testing link 3</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">4</div> <a href="#">Testing link 4</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">1</div> <a href="#">Testing link 1</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">5</div> <a href="#">Testing link 5</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="document-item">
        <div class="number">6</div> <a href="#">Testing link 6</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Css Style

give width:100% to (.document-list) and in .document-item  use float:left; width:50%

```
.document-list {
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-bottom:15px; width:100%;
}
.number {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0084c9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #0084c9;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
}
.document-item {
    margin-bottom:8px;
    float:left;
    width:50%
}
```

see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Efc4V/

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS under your CSS.

CSS Code:

```
.document-item:hover a{
    color:#91c64e;
}
.document-item:hover .number{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #91c64e;
    background-color:#91c64e;
    border-radius: 50000px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
}
```